# Understanding 女の方が願い下げ

Tags: meaning, set-phrases

I am uncertain how to understand 女の方が願い下げ in the below panel:

[image]

I  believe it means "women won't accept a man like him"? Perhaps "he has no interest in women"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Women won't accept a man like him' is basically correct.

`願い下げ` is listed as follows in [大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%A1%98%E3%81%84%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%92/#jn-169763).

> ２ 頼まれても断ること。「そんな話ならこちらから—だ」

The last part of the previous bubble says the guy looks like interested only in a certain type of girls (and not in others). Then the sentence says girls (including those 'other' he shows no interest in) would turn him down even if he asks.

Answer (score 0):

These two frames revolve around the discussion that he is still virgin at the age of 24 because he has very high standards regarding women.

In the second frame, one person says "He's only interested in the typical female characters you'd expect from mangas and games", to which the second person (most likely a female) asnwers "The women won't want him".

The translation above is acceptable but it would be better translated as "The women won't want him [even if he accepts them]", which is being nuanced.